# Create a windows universal app using angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, windows-store-apps

How to create a windows universal app with angularjs?

I created an universal windows app using visual studio, added the angular script (for testing purposes, I tried it on different ways with bower, manually and with nuget) and always get "Unable to add dynamic content".

Searching for this I found a lot of links trying to explain how to get around this error, for example: http://blog.kadople.com/2013/06/getting-started-with-angularjs-in.html. But it all seems to be very ugly or not working at all - at least not for windows universal apps. The demo app of the link mentioned is working but that involved hacking around in jquery code adding execUnsafeLocalFunction and that is something I really don't want to do. And I think this should be working with jquery version >= 2.0 - but ok, it is not.

How can we make this app "universal"? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great solution to this problem is to [WinStore-JsCompat](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/winstore-jscompat) in your project. Just include it and add a reference in you .html file before all other scripts and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Universal app development can be tricky, especially if you are using angularjs. As suggested by [Sorskoot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31722/sorskoot), winstore-jscompat is required to be able to use angularjs in your universal windows app.

I suggest using [this fork](https://github.com/ClemMakesApps/winstore-jscompat/blob/master/winstore-jscompat.js) of jscompat by [AndyB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2457441/andyb) that I found to be working with my test project.

Try adding `ng-csp` attribute to your Angularjs app as mentioned in their docs for windows universal apps https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCsp

You are now two steps closer to making a "universal" windows app!

Comment: And as one can read "Note: You do not need to include this file for Windows 10 apps.", it seems that all this stuff is automatically done for Windows 10 apps. 

Unfortunately it seems to have some minor performance implications as one can read on the same website "Please note that there may be a minor impact on your app's performance, the extent of which depends upon the specific usage, timing, and frequency of the three property calls listed above." (Source: https://github.com/MsopenTech/winstore-jscompat) Thanks for your help.