# VS Cordova with AngularJS for Windows 8.1 Store App

Tags: windows, angularjs, cordova

I downloaded and deployed the 2 AngularJS demos below 
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/AngularJS-TODO-Sample-for-b651512a
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/AngularJS-Detail-Sample-7a409e5e/view/Discussions

I deployed them to WP8 and Android devices and they worked fine.
But when I deployed to Windows 8 Store App, the input box does not work.
Both demos have the same issues.

I tried using VS 2013 and VS 2015. The outcomes are the same.

Am I missing any build setting? Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

I searched this few days. Add:

> ng-csp

to html tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-csp>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>BlankCordovaApp1</title>
<!-- BlankCordovaApp1 references -->
<link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Cordova reference, this is added to your app when it's built. -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="">
<p>Hello, your application is ready!</p>
<input type="text" value="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to my [stackoverflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22969190/create-a-windows-universal-app-using-angularjs/30657969#30657969) for a similar problem.

There are a few things you may want to check in your app - the version of jQuery should be >= 2.x, `ng-csp`is added to your index.html and `winstore-jscompat`library is added to your project.

These are common issues that windows 8.1 apps with angularjs/jQuery throw. Hope this helps!