# Jquery , Angular js and jq.appframework errors in windows 8 cordova app

Tags: angularjs, windows, cordova

I am getting some issue in loading jquery and related libraries in windows8 cordova app.

I am having JQuery version 1.9.1

Errors are:

jquery.js0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError

angular.js0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngLocale' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument. errors.angularjs.org/1.2.8/$injector/nomod?p0=ngLocale

jq.appframework.js 0x80004005 JavaScript runtime error

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: this is a bug with the version of angular you are using.  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8174.  It was fixed in a later release.  If you update to a newer version of Angular, you will get the error reporting the *actual* module that can't be loaded.

Comment: Thanks Claies for your response. I am using Angular js version 1.2.8 and upgraded it to 1.3.9 but still the same issue exists and I am getting same error in output window . Any other suggestions? Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: if you post some sample code where you are using `ngLocale`, it will be easier to tell why it thinks you are using it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

The `ngLocale` module injection error is misleading to say the least as it indicates that `some` module, not necessarily `ngLocale` is not available.

As John Papa explains in [his blog](http://www.johnpapa.net/easy-fix-to-a-common-angular-module-error/), the error message dearly needs a refactoring to make better sense!

Unfortunately there is no short-cut to identify the cause for the dependency error - the only way would be to check each module that you are trying to add to the app.

However it is worth looking into [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22969190/create-a-windows-universal-app-using-angularjs/30657969#30657969) for issues with windows universal app using angularjs. Adding `ng-csp` directive and `winstore-jscompat` library as mentioned in [the stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22969190/create-a-windows-universal-app-using-angularjs/30657969#30657969) will help.